# Smart and fast way to store a lot of text data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm facing a problem when dealing with a large table with many records in it (MySQL by the way).

I have two scenarios. The first one is a single table with a primary key and 18 different varchar fields.

| id | Field1 | Field2 | Field18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | abc | abc |
| 2 | def | def | def |
| 100 | xyz | xyz | xyz |

The second scenario is that I have a single table that organizes all information in a different way:

| id_record | field_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | field1 | abc |
| 1 | field2 | abc |
| 1 | field3 | abc |
| 2 | field1 | def |
| 100 | field18 | xyz |

On the first I have a fixed structure (no flexibility) and may have a lot of blank spaces. On the second solution I can easily add new fields but the table will grow quickly.

On some tests I ran both perform well at about 200 000 records stored. But as I grow it (I tested with 500 000 and 1M) things get painful slow on the second scenario.

On the second id_record and field_name are indexes and value is fulltext. But it does not help much.

When I try to combine two matches things get specially slow:

```
select f1.id_record from table f1 where f1.field = 'field1' and f1.value like '%abc%' and f1.id_record in (
    select f2.id_record from table f2 where f2.field = 'field18' and f2.value like '%abc%'
);
```

or

```
select f1.id_record from table f1, table f2 where f1.field = 'field1' and f2.field = 'field18' and f1.id_record = f2.id_record and f1.value like '%abc%' and f2.value like '%abc%';
```

Any ideas on how to perform better on the second scenario? Or if there's any new ideas on how to structure better this kind of data?

Comment: If you are familiar with python then I will strongly recommend you to use mysql-connecter with python. You can write a script that will take any kind of file as input and store that data into MySQL.

Comment: What indices have you created? The second scenario is The Dreaded Cross Join, so it might not be what you want.

Comment: I'm using PHP so it won't work. And I'm using separate index for id_record and `field` columns and fulltext for `value` column

Comment: Is your typical query looking for a substring in some of the columns?  Are those substrings "words"?

Comment: I may search for the full text or just part of it and the text is a sentence (rarely I will store a full text, but may happen once in a while). That's actually not my main concern. It's the performance vs flexibility. If I go to the traditional table I have a limited number of columns that I need to set up. So I may end up with lot of null values or run out of slots. Using the second method I have more flexibility, I store only valid data (no need to store null values) but I grow that table pretty quickly and performance starts to deteriorate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have exactly 18 columns and don't need to add more, then the first is a very reasonable way to store the data.  The query that you want is simply:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.field like '%abc%' and t.field2 like '%abc%';
```

Unfortunately, this query requires a full-table scan (because of the wildcards in the `like`).  Without using a full text index, this is probably the best that you can do unless the data is quite sparse.

The second structure gives you two possibilities for the above query.  One uses `JOIN`:

```
select f1.id_record
from table f1 join
     table f2 
     on f1.id_record = f2.id_record
where f1.field = 'field1' and f2.field = 'field18' and
      f1.value like '%abc%' and f2.value like '%abc%';
```

The best index for this is `(id_record, field, value)`.  This might have okay performance if `field1` or `field18` are quite sparse.

I usually recommend `group by`, for this type of query:

```
select f.id_record
from table f
where (f.field = 'field1' and f.value like '%abc%') and
      (f.field = 'field18' and f.value like '%abc%')
group by f.id_record
having count(*) = 2;
```

However, I recommend `group by` because of its flexibility, not specifically because of its performance.

Comment: 18 was not a specific number, maybe I forgot to mention that on my first question. I mean I have a certain text columns on scenario 1 and my concern is that it may not be enough for certain situations. That's why I came across scenario 2 which would be much more flexible in that way but slower as the number of records grows.

Comment: @racquad - Yes, EAV is more "flexible"...  And slow... And clumsy.

Comment: @RickJames is there any other option? Or is the first method better?

Comment: @racquad - show us the `FULLTEXT` version.